# Fill in the day dates with week end date available

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with multiple ids and week end dates for those ids. I’d like to make that table into a days table. Here’s a sample of what I have:

| ID | week_end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/8/2016 |
| 1 | 1/15/2016 |
| 1 | 1/22/2016 |
| 2 | 9/17/20217 |
| 2 | 9/24/2017 |
| 2 | 10/1/2017 |
| 3 | 6/15/2019 |
| 3 | 6/22/2019 |
| 3 | 6/29/2019 |

Notice that the week_end_date is on a different day of the week for each of the sample ids, id 1 - Friday, id 2 - Sunday, id 3 - Saturday.
What I’m trying to achieve is a table that would have rows for each day between (and including) the week_end_date. I want my table to look something like this

| ID | day_date | is_week_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/8/2016 | Yes |
| 1 | 1/9/2016 | No |
| 1 | 1/10/2016 | No |
| 1 | 1/11/2016 | No |
| 1 | 1/12/2016 | No |
| 1 | 1/13/2016 | No |
| 1 | 1/14/2016 | No |
| 1 | 1/15/2016 | Yes |
| … |  |  |
| 2 | 9/17/2017 | Yes |
| 2 | 9/18/2017 | No |
| 2 | 9/19/2017 | No |
| 2 | 9/20/2017 | No |
| 2 | 9/21/2017 | No |
| 2 | 9/22/2017 | No |
| 2 | 9/23/2017 | No |
| 2 | 9/24/2017 | Yes |
| … |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

You may use LAG() window function to get previous week_end_date. Then create a list of dates between ends of weeks with GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(). And flatten the array with UNNEST() function + CROSS JOIN to merge it back to the original table:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
SELECT 1 as ID, DATE '2016-01-08' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as ID, DATE '2016-01-15' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as ID, DATE '2016-01-22' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as ID, DATE '2017-09-17' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as ID, DATE '2017-09-24' as week_end_date
)
select ID, day_date,
  CASE WHEN week_end_date = day_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_week_end_date
from (
  select *, LAG(week_end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY week_end_date) as prev_week_end_date
  from sample_data
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
  CASE WHEN prev_week_end_date is null then week_end_date else prev_week_end_date END,
  week_end_date,
  INTERVAL 1 day)) as day_date
```

In case you need previous 6 days for every week_end_date:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
SELECT 1 as ID, DATE '2016-01-08' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as ID, DATE '2016-01-15' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as ID, DATE '2016-01-22' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as ID, DATE '2017-09-17' as week_end_date UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as ID, DATE '2017-09-24' as week_end_date
)
select ID, day_date,
  CASE WHEN week_end_date = day_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as is_week_end_date
from sample_data
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
  DATE_ADD(week_end_date, INTERVAL -6 day), 
  week_end_date,
  INTERVAL 1 day)) as day_date
```

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much! Is there a way to also add the preceding weekdays before the first end date date for every ID? So for example in the case of the ID 1 the first week end date is 1/8/2016 is it possible to add dates from 1/2/2016 to 1/7/2016?

Comment: You are welcome! I have added second query to the answer. Hope that is what you are looking for.